# Add a custom style on hover + L-Click like file explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of elements like this: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/646025006525972480/867398145684275210/unknown.png

I need to reproduce the behavior of a file explorer in the way that I select them.

To be clearer, when I hoover the element + left click it would create a sort of virtual rectangle to select all the elements in this rectangle (The same behavior that the windows explorer has when you select many files)

I tried to do something with some Jquery (by listening mouse up/ down events and hover related events) but nothing is working as I want.

Do you have any idea of how I could do something similar please ?

Comment: Could you post the code of your try?

Comment: Do you mean shift+click the element? So that if I click an element, it becomes selected, and then if I shift+click another element, that new element and all the ones in between are selected?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ua2d15Lv/3/).
Here on clicking the item, it's getting selected (backgroundcolor change with border) and if you click the same item again it'll get deselected.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <ul class="list_wrap">
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list_wrap li').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
        $(this).removeClass('selected')
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass('selected')
    }
  })
})
```

CSS:

```
.selected{
  background:#f1f1f1;
  border:solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is using **right click**..
anyway, in jquery that's how you do it

```
var notepad = document.getElementById("notepad");
notepad.addEventListener("contextmenu",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var ctxMenu = document.getElementById("ctxMenu");
    ctxMenu.style.display = "block";
    ctxMenu.style.left = (event.pageX - 10)+"px";
    ctxMenu.style.top = (event.pageY - 10)+"px";
},false);
notepad.addEventListener("click",function(event){
    var ctxMenu = document.getElementById("ctxMenu");
    ctxMenu.style.display = "";
    ctxMenu.style.left = "";
    ctxMenu.style.top = "";
},false);
```

This is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w33z4bo0/1/) to represent it visually, hope this would help.

Comment: What I want is not a ctx menu but something to select items in my list as if I was in a file explorer but thanks !